# android gridview fit the size in to screen

Tags: android, gridview

The gridview of my application has an image and a text below it for each grid.
I need to make sure that the complete list of  grid fit in to the screen (no overflow at bottom).

Here is how i have defined my gridview

```
<GridView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/gridview" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
         android:numColumns="3"
        android:stretchMode="columnWidth"
        android:layout_below="@+id/text1view" 
                     android:gravity="center"
                    android:background="@drawable/home_bg"

                                />
```

and each grid item is :

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   android:id="@+id/GridItem"
   android:layout_width="wrap_content"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:orientation="vertical"
   android:gravity="center_horizontal"
  >

   <ImageView android:id="@+id/grid_item_image"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:padding="0dip"
      android:layout_margin="0dip"
      >
   </ImageView>

   <TextView android:id="@+id/grid_item_text"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
           android:textColor="#000000"
           android:padding="0dip"
      android:gravity="center_horizontal"
      android:layout_below="@+id/grid_item_image"
      android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
      >
   </TextView>

</LinearLayout>
```

I have tried several ways to set the grid view layout param, but i am not getting the right output. Please help me here. the gridview adapter code is

```
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    ViewHolder holder;

    if (convertView == null) {
        LayoutInflater mInflater = (LayoutInflater) mContext
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.griditems, null);
        holder = new ViewHolder();
        holder.text1 = (TextView) convertView
                .findViewById(R.id.grid_item_text);
        Log.i(TAG, holder.text1.toString());
        holder.image = (ImageView) convertView
                .findViewById(R.id.grid_item_image);

        // if it's not recycled, initialize some attributes
        holder.image.setImageResource(gridItemIds[position]);
        holder.text1.setText(gridTitles[position]);
        int h = mContext.getResources().getDisplayMetrics().densityDpi;
        convertView.setLayoutParams(new GridView.LayoutParams(h-50, h-20));
        //holder.image.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_CROP);
        //holder.image.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.FIT_XY); ......
```

Comment: can u show some images.how does ur layout look now.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:-

grid_item.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:orientation="vertical"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">
 <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/linearLayout1" android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:orientation="vertical" android:gravity="center">
<ImageView android:id="@+id/imgIcon" android:src="@drawable/icon" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"></ImageView>
<TextView android:text="TextView" android:id="@+id/txtDesc"   android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_width="wrap_content"></TextView>
</LinearLayout>   
</LinearLayout>
```

gridview.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
>
<GridView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:id="@+id/mobGrid"
android:layout_width="match_parent" 
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:padding="10dp"
android:verticalSpacing="10dp"
android:horizontalSpacing="10dp"
android:numColumns="auto_fit"
android:columnWidth="60dp"
android:stretchMode="columnWidth"
android:gravity="center"
/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score -1):

try

```
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
```

for your GridView instead of wrap_content!